# How can I remove all the space around my canvas element?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, spacing

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

.canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    width: calc(100vw - 6px);
    height: calc(100vh - 6px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But for some reason, there is still space around the canvas (besides my margin and border). I used the same CSS for the first version of this project, that I needed to delete for reasons, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Please can you attach a screenshot and some browser info? The canvas renders correctly for me.

Comment: Why are you giving `.canvas` a margin? Not really sure what you mean, could you provide a screenshot, or something perhaps?

Comment: all you need is display:block to the canvas, no more complex code, it's a whitespace issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it necessary? In order to remove this space, the parent `container` needs to be set, in this case, this `body` tag should be set to the dimensions of the `width` and `height`.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height: calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

VH and VW are View height and View width. as such - they are the measurments of the screen sans any console url navigator. the View.

the reason you are getting white space is you are Calculating a new number... which is slightly smaller than the entire screen - by 6px, because you are shrinking 100% view coverage by subtracting px's from both height and width.

margin on the canvas also is a reason for you seeing white space....

margin ->border ->padding ->content is the nesting for that model. margin is just adding space to the element - which is space AROUND the element {space directly OUTSIDE the border} - (margins combine with other margins) - where padding increases space inside of the border of the div - margin increase space right outside the border of the targeted element.

so if you're goal is to fit it to 100% of the screen. you just need VH/VW to be set to 100; and nix the margin.

if you're goal is to fit it into 100% of the div container it is in... VH VW are the wrong measure units to use for that.

here is some code I did on codepen to test.

this results in the canvas covering the screen, leaving no space other than the canvas.

```
html

<html>
<body>
    <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```
css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
}
.canvas {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```
js test

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, as I said in my post, I wanted to remove the space that wasn't the border or the margin, which is why I subtracted 6px from the vh and vw, so it would fit just right. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: my apologies if I didn't understand the question. the the margin->border->padding->content model... you want the content to be right next to the border with no padding... is that accurate?